# AWS IAM role for use within a classroom

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm trying to create an AWS IAM role for use within a classroom.

The aim is to have one account for centralised billing, but each student has a set of credential to log them into the AWS console they can manage certain resources. For example, I want users to be able to start/stop EC2 instances in us-east-1 of size t2.micro or t2.small based on the official AMIs.

From what I understand, it's scenario 2 from https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/aws-setting-up-multiuser-environments-education.pdf. However I can't find any working examples of the IAM policies.

I've tried to create an IAM to cover the scenario but it doesn't appear to work as expected. When I attempt to create an accepted instance I get errors about creating a VPC. The other also can see existing keypairs/security groups.

It's important that only users who create the instance and view/manage them.

Here is what I tried:

`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeImages",
                "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:account:instance/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:account:key-pair/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:account:security-group/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:account:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:account:volume/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:account:instance/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:account:key-pair/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:account:security-group/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:account:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:account:volume/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:account:instance:instance/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:InstanceType": "t1.small"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::image/ami-*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:Owner": "amazon"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "ec2:StartInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:account:instance/*"
        }
    ]
}`

I'm assuming account is a special keyword that refers to the account the policy has been applied to.

Answer (score 1):

> It's important that only users who create the instance and view/manage
>   them.

This is very difficult to do with users in the same account (and the whitepaper you link to makes no promises about it).  You can limit actual instance shell access easily through SSH keys, but the AWS-level instance management pieces are harder to separate.  EC2 IAM permissions do not offer a statically-definable way to allow a specific user to create an instance and then be the only user that can modify or terminate that instance.  (You can only limit the instance termination and modification ability of a user to a specific instance by using the instance ID, which is only created once that instance has been created.)  (As an aside, you also won't be able to limit the number of instances a single user can have running at once, for example.  Again, a capability AWS simply does not offer.)

If you want that kind of separation of abilities, you will either need to go with whitepaper scenario 1 (you create and manage the instances and each student gets a unique ssh key just on their assigned server) or 3 (each student gets a separate account, although again, you would probably want to create and manage the IAM roles and instance limits for each account to prevent unintended expenses).